# JavaScript simple code not running

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm watching a tutorial and I tried running the following code but it doesn't run.

```
var person = {
  'address': {
    'street': 'Rose Road',
    'city': 'somewhere',
    'state': 'CA'
  },
  'isfromState': fucntion(state) {
    return (this.address.state === state);
  }
}
console.log(person.isfromState('blah'));
```

Instead, it gives me this error `Exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list` and I can't find the mistake.

Comment: `fucntion` should be `function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'isfromState': fucntion(state) { // <--- fucntion isn't a keyword
  return (this.address.state === state);
}
```

Should be:

```
'isfromState': function(state) { // <--- use function
  return (this.address.state === state);
}
```

Comment: Given the error this isnt the problem (although certainly *a* problem!). Although I've tried a few variations and can not get the `SyntaxError` reported, its often a missing comma somewhere, which isn't the case with the snippet.